# Splash screen is flipping from landscape to portrait when starting app

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build, splash-screen

This is my first app. For this particular issue, I am seeing it when using *PhoneGap Build* and testing on an iPhone 6 with iOS 9.2.1.

From what I researched, it appears to be the splash screen plugin - which is fixed in version 3.4. The version of the plugin in the app build seems to be 3.2, so I figured that it just wasn't released yet. I haven't specified a version in the config.xml, so it should be pulling the latest version. See the link I posted below in an answer for further details on what I am talking about.

I am testing an app built using PhoneGap Build and on my iPhone 6, it displays the splash screen nicely at first, but then flips to portrait and uses a very large image, so I just see part of the splash screen. I have the app set as landscape only and don't have anything in the written code that calls the splash screen. The iOS settings I have are:

```
<platform name="ios">
    <!-- Portrait -->
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/480x320.png" width="320" height="480"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/960x640.png" width="640" height="960"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/1024x768.png" width="768" height="1024"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/1136x640.png" width="640" height="1136"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/1334x750.png" width="750" height="1334"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/2048x1536.png" width="1536" height="2048"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/2208x1242.png" width="1242" height="2208"/>

    <!-- Landscape -->
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/480x320.png" width="480" height="320"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/960x640.png" width="960" height="640"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/1024x768.png" width="1024" height="768"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/1136x640.png" width="1136" height="640"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/1334x750.png" width="1334" height="750"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/2048x1536.png" width="2048" height="1536"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/2208x1242.png" width="2208" height="1242"/>     
</platform>
```

I have played around and seems that the landscape images do not get used at all. The portrait ones are the landscape images I created to appear proper initially. Any idea what I need to do to make sure that the splash screen always is in landscape and using the correct image?

A second part to this. I don't have a default splash specified because I don't know the specs it should be. Any idea? Thanks.

To be clear on questions asked in the comments: I am using the *Desktop App* ONLY for some basic testing, and I am aware that it does not use my config.xml file

Comment: Thanks Jesse. I have added the information you asked for, along with some additional details.

Comment: It doesn't play into it at all. Its just another method of testing before I zip up the code and upload for the build.

Comment: PhoneGap Desktop doesn't have anything to do with this issue because it doesn't display the splash screen when testing. This issue is when I use PhoneGap Build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like an issue with the Cordova Splash Screen plugin. It is marked as fixed, but not released yet. It appears to be set to version 3.4, which the latest version of the plugin is 3.2. See [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-3562) for details.

In the meantime, I ended up removing the plugin for now, which shows the splash screen properly in iOS for a second before hitting the app.